# Infinite loop error in for loop in c programming when writing code to find out gcd

Tags: c

so i tried writing a program to find gcd of two numbers. but the output comes out as an infinite loop. I don't understand why this is happening. Can someone please explain why the output is an infinte loop?

Output comes out as `1818181818...`
when i run the code
1 being "t"
and 8 being the second integer 8
which I printed to see if the code is printing anything because no output was showing without these before i printed "b" and "t".
I just want why the output is an infinite loop.
I am new to c programming.
below is the code i typed:

```
// Write a program to find the HCF of two integers entered by the user.
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, hcf, t, f1, f2;
    printf("enter the first integer");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter the second integer");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    for (t = 1; t <= a / 2; a++)
    {

        if (a % t == 0)
        {
            f1 = t;
            printf("%d",f1);}
            if (b % f1 == 0)
            {printf("%d",b);
                hcf = f1;
            
        }
    }
    printf("%d", hcf);
    
}
```

output:

```
enter the first integer6
enter the second integer8
18181818181818181818181818...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t++` in the for loop instead of `a++`?

Comment: ```t``` never changes..

Comment: Your indentation is very misleading. Once indented properly, you'll see you could be taking a `% f1` before f1 has been set to anything. (It seems that you might get away with it, since the first 'if' will always succeed, but it is still very gross.)

Comment: Debugger.......

Answer (score 0):

`t` is always 1 , while `a` is incrementing , so the condition of loop `t <= a/2` is always true

and because `t` is 1 , the condition of `a % t == 0` is always `true` also , so it prints the value of `f1` that is 1.
Then the next condition `b % f1 == 0` while `f1` gets have the value 1 this condition is `true` also , so it prints the value of `b` (it's the 8 in your case)

try :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int a , b , gcd ; 
    printf("the first indicator :");
    scanf ("%d",&a);
    printf("the second indicator :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int min = a < b ? a : b ;
    for(int i=1;i<min;i++){
        if( ( a % i == 0 ) && ( b % i == 0 ) ){
            gcd = i ;
            printf(" the number %d is a commun devisor of %d and %d \n",gcd, a, b);
        }
    }
    if( gcd != 1 ) 
        printf("the GCD of %d and %d is %d",a,b,gcd) ; 
    else
        printf(" there is no GCD of %d and %d",a,b) ; 
    
    return 0;
}
```